# Kentico 9 form macros and different notification recipient based on dropdown value

Tags: kentico

I have a form field as a drop down (ReasonForMessage) with the data like this:

```
email1@test.com;Reason One
email2@test.com;Reason Two
```

So user can select a reason, and then the notification would be send to address attached to that reason. If the Email Notification, for the recipient emails, how do i grab just them email portion with a macro.

Is this correct?
{% ReasonForMessage %}

And how do i get the second part of the data, the actual Reason?

I'm basing this on this article (https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-send-form-notifications-to-different-emails-based-on-field-values) just not sure it's still valid with Kentico 9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.
You can try using a delimiter to store both the email and display text, like the colon below...

info@company.com:General;General
sales@company.com:Sales;Sales
support@company.com:Support;Support

Then, to get the individual stored values use Split() to get the email and display text respectively...

{% category.Split(":")[0] %}
{% category.Split(":")[1] %}